# How do I prevent SQL injection in a LIKE '%input%' clause?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, sql-injection, sql-like

I’m using SQLAlchemy with PostgreSQL and I need to generate a statement like

```
SELECT * FROM entities WHERE name LIKE '%input%';
```

where the “input” bit of the LIKE string is coming from a user. I would like the user to be able to include literal `%` and `_` characters and have these match exactly, and obviously I need to ensure that the query doesn’t allow SQL injection. What is the idiomatic way to do this in SQLAlchemy? I tried

```
entities = session.query(Entity).filter(Entity.name.like('%:text%')) \
               .params(text=user_input).all()
```

but this didn’t seem to work—it executed without complaint but did not match rows that should have matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`contains()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains) and [`autoescape=True`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains.params.autoescape):

```
Entity.name.contains(user_input, autoescape=True)
```

Given `autoescape=True` SQLAlchemy will establish an escape character and escape occurrences of `"%"`, `"_"` and the escape character itself. You can control the escape character explicitly using the [`escape=`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.contains.params.escape) parameter.